# Splitting a string at all whitespace

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to split a string at all whitespace, it should ONLY contain the words themselves.

How can I do this in vb.net?

Tabs, Newlines, etc. must all be split!

This has been bugging me for quite a while now, as my syntax highlighter I made completely ignores the first word in each line except for the very first line.

Comment: See also possible duplicate with SplitStringOptions to remove the extra whitespace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation

Answer (score 31, accepted):

String.Split() (no parameters) does split on all whitespace (including LF/CR)

Comment: Why didn't they include that as an overload lol? Thanks so much!

Comment: because it resolves to the Split(params char[]) overload, with an empty array. The documentation for that overload mentions this behavior.

Comment: CAUTION: As Johannes Rudolph mentions in his answer, if there are multiple whitespace characters in a row, String.Split will contain empty elements. That is why Rubens Farias answer is superior.

Comment: Adam Ralph's solution of using String.Split().Where(...) has quicker performance than the Regex solution.  I posted test results below.

Comment: @ToolMakerSteve - to remove empty elements `String.Split(new char[] {}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @Joe, VS says "identifier expected" for me.

Comment: @Joe great idea, thanks! Simpler: `line.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
Regex.Split("your string here", "\s+")
```

Comment: It's C#. you should be fine without.

Answer (score 6):

**If you want to avoid regex**, you can do it like this:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
    .Split()
    .Where(x => x != string.Empty)
```

Visual Basic equivalent:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" _
    .Split() _
    .Where(Function(X$) X <> String.Empty)
```

The `Where()` is important since, if your string has multiple white space characters next to each other, it removes the empty strings that will result from the `Split()`.

At the time of writing, the currently accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563000/49241) does not take this into account.

Comment: great solution.  Not only does it avoid the need for a Regex reference but it's also quicker (see my post below). I'd like to add that I don't think VB makes use of the lambda operator "=>", so the VB version of this is a little different, I think like this: s.Split().Where(Function(x) x <> String.Empty)

Comment: Hey @u8it, I have added a VB .NET version to this answer. I just read your comment a few days after editing the answer!!!

Comment: @Sree your edit is incorrect. The Visual Basic version is _not_ the equivalent of the C# version because it uses `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` instead of the `!=` operator to compare with `String.Empty`. Can you please fix it? I don't know what the Visual Basic syntax for that is.

Comment: @Adam I have put a `Not`, as in `Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(X))`… the Not operator negates a Boolean value. Is that what you were telling about?

Comment: I've tried my edit with a sample string as well (before posting the edit), and it worked perfectly as asked by OP. Am I missing anything you said?

Comment: @Sree you labelled your edit as a "Visual Basic equivalent". `Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(X)` is not the Visual Basic equivalent of `x != string.Empty`.

Comment: Hmm, I see. At this point, they both basically do the same thing, but thank you for the clarification. I'll update it.

Comment: @Sree I've made the appropriate edit. I tested the VB version in LINQPad to make sure it works.

Answer (score 2):

`String.Split()` will split on every single whitespace, so the result will contain empty strings usually. The Regex solution Ruben Farias has given is the correct way to do it. I have upvoted his answer but I want to give a small addition, dissecting the regex:

`\s` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches all whitespace characters.

In order to split the string correctly when it contains multiple whitespace characters between words, we need to add a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (or repetition operator) to the specification to match all whitespace between words. The correct quantifier to use in this case is `+`, meaning "one or more" occurrences of a given specification. While the syntax `"\s+"` is sufficient here, I prefer the more explicit "`[\s]+`".

Comment: As usual, we now have two problems instead of one... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

So, after seeing Adam Ralph's post, I suspected his solution of being faster than the Regex solution. Just thought I'd share the results of my testing since I did find it was faster.

---

There are really two factors at play (ignoring system variables): number of sub-strings extracted (determined by number of delimiters), and total string length.  The very simple scenario plotted below uses "A" as the sub-string delimited by two white space characters (a space followed by tab).  This accentuates the effect of number of sub-strings extracted. I went ahead and did some multiple variable testing to arrive at the following general equations for my operating system.

**Regex()**
t = (28.33*SSL + 572)(SSN/10^6)

**Split().Where()**
t = (6.23*SSL + 250)(SSN/10^6)

*Where t is execution time in milliseconds, SSL is average sub-string length, and SSN is number of sub-strings delimited in string.*

These equations can also written as

t = (28.33*SL + 572*SSN)/10^6

and

t = (6.23*SL + 250*SSN)/10^6

where SL is total string length (SL = SSL * SSN)

**Conclusion:** The Split().Where() solution is faster than Regex().  The major factor is number of sub-strings, while string length plays a minor role. Performance gains are about 2x and 5x for the respective coefficients.

---

[image]

---

Here's my testing code (probably way more material than necessary, but it's set-up for getting the multi-variable data I talked about)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum TestMethods {regex, split};
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Compare TestMethod execution times and output result information
            //to the console at runtime and to the clipboard at program finish (so that data is ready to paste into analysis environment)
            #region Config_Variables
            //Choose test method from TestMethods enumerator (regex or split)
            TestMethods TestMethod = TestMethods.split;
            //Configure RepetitionString
            String RepetitionString =  string.Join(" \t", Enumerable.Repeat("A",100));
            //Configure initial and maximum count of string repetitions (final count may not equal max)
            int RepCountInitial = 100;int RepCountMax = 1000 * 100;

            //Step increment to next RepCount (calculated as 20% increase from current value)
            Func<int, int> Step = x => (int)Math.Round(x / 5.0, 0);
            //Execution count used to determine average speed (calculated to adjust down to 1 execution at long execution times)
            Func<double, int> ExecutionCount = x => (int)(1 + Math.Round(500.0 / (x + 1), 0));
            #endregion

            #region NonConfig_Variables
            string s; 
            string Results = "";
            string ResultInfo; 
            double ResultTime = 1;
            #endregion

            for (int RepCount = RepCountInitial; RepCount < RepCountMax; RepCount += Step(RepCount))
            {
                s = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(RepetitionString, RepCount));
                ResultTime = Test(s, ExecutionCount(ResultTime), TestMethod);
                ResultInfo = ResultTime.ToString() + "\t" + RepCount.ToString() + "\t" + ExecutionCount(ResultTime).ToString() + "\t" + TestMethod.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(ResultInfo); 
                Results += ResultInfo + "\r\n";
            }
            Clipboard.SetText(Results);
        }
        public static double Test(string s, int iMax, TestMethods Method)
        {
            switch (Method)
            {
                case TestMethods.regex:
                    return Math.Round(RegexRunTime(s, iMax),2);
                case TestMethods.split:
                    return Math.Round(SplitRunTime(s, iMax),2);
                default:
                    return -1;
            }
        }
        private static double RegexRunTime(string s, int iMax)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
            {
                System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> ens = Regex.Split(s, @"\s+");
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return Math.Round(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / (double)iMax, 2);
        }
        private static double SplitRunTime(string s,int iMax)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
            {
                System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> ens = s.Split().Where(x => x != string.Empty);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return Math.Round(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / (double)iMax, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice amount of effort but both solutions are suboptimal. Just use `str.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead of filtering out the empty strings from the result.

Comment: That looks like a good option too. Did you compare it? I'm wondering what the performance comes down to, for instance, compiler optimization, maybe it's very similar in the IL.

Comment: Post-filtering by a `WhereIterator` definitely an additional cost. I created a quick [performance test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDB9bg).

Answer (score 1):

I found I used the solution as noted by Adam Ralph, plus the VB.NET comment below by P57, but with one odd exception.
I found I had to add .ToList.ToArray on the end.

Like so:

```
.Split().Where(Function(x) x <> String.Empty).ToList.ToArray
```

Without that, I kept getting "*Unable to cast object of type 'WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.*"

Comment: I was able to make this work fine with only: .Split().Where(Function(x) x <> String.Empty).ToArray

Comment: You're welcome.  I guess I should have also said at that time that it was using VS2013 and .Net 4.5.2, just in case it was a recent change.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim words As String = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" + _
                          vbTab + "and a tab character." + vbNewLine
Dim split As String() = words.Split(New [Char]() {" "c, CChar(vbTab), CChar(vbNewLine) })
```