# Best way to specify whitespace in a String.Split operation

Tags: c#, string

I am splitting a string based on whitespace as follows:

```
string myStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
string[] ssizes = myStr.Split(whitespace);
```

It's irksome to define the char[] array everywhere in my code I want to do this. Is there more efficent way that doesn't require the creation of the character array (which is prone to error if copied in different places)?

Comment: does this: myStr.Split(' '); not work?

Comment: If I understand this correctly this will only search for a space, not generic whitespace

Comment: See also possible duplicate, but these later answers have SplitStringOptions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562981/splitting-a-string-at-all-whitespace

Answer (score 543, accepted):

If you just call:

```
string[] ssize = myStr.Split(null); //Or myStr.Split()
```

or:

```
string[] ssize = myStr.Split(new char[0]);
```

then white-space is assumed to be the splitting character. From the [`string.Split(char[])` method's documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split).

> *If the separator parameter is `null` or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return `true` if they are passed to the [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace) method.*

Always, always, **always** read the documentation!

Comment: The trouble with splitting by whitespace is if you have to put it together again, you don't know which whitespace character to put back.

Comment: `(char[])null` is slightly better as it avoids creating a new object. (You can't use `null` with any of the `options` overloads).

Comment: @RossPresser: Putting a string back together is a completely different problem, so I wouldn't say this is a problem here. But if all you need to do is put the string back together exactly how it was before, then perhaps better just keep the original.

Comment: Not necessarily EXACTLY like it was. Something like "capitalize the first character of each word, unless it matches this stopword list" is a good example for where you need the original split characters.

Comment: Stupid question, but if you use `null`, do you still need to specify the `StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries` or are they ignored by default?

Comment: StringSplitOptions.None is the default

Comment: @RossPresser: Since String.Split does not provide any mechanism for keeping track of the characters used to split the string, your observation is not relevant: one cannot achieve what you seek using String.Split, so that requires a different Q&A.

Comment: Thank you for that. In some of my strings the whitespace apparently was not a ' '-character and thus the strings were not split correctly. Using this method all whitespaces were recognized correctly.

Comment: That's not an answer. What do you pass to `IndexOf` or `TrimStart` then ?

Comment: string[] ssize = myStr.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) will remove empty entries too.

Comment: can we use above somehow to include whitespaces and other character like a , ? –

Answer (score 264):

Yes, There is need for one more answer here!

All the solutions thus far address the rather limited domain of *canonical input*, to wit: a ***single*** whitespace character *between* elements (though tip of the hat to @cherno for at least mentioning the problem).
But I submit that in all but the most obscure scenarios, splitting all of these *should* yield identical results:

```
string myStrA = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string myStrB = "The  quick  brown  fox  jumps  over  the  lazy  dog";
string myStrC = "The quick brown fox      jumps over the lazy dog";
string myStrD = "   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

`String.Split` (in any of the flavors shown throughout the other answers here) simply does not work well unless you attach the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option with either of these:

```
myStr.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
myStr.Split(new char[] {' ','\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

As the illustration reveals, omitting the option yields four different results (labeled A, B, C, and D) vs. the single result from all four inputs when you use `RemoveEmptyEntries`:

[image: String.Split vs Regex.Split]

Of course, if you don't like using options, just use the regex alternative :-)

```
Regex.Split(myStr, @"\s+").Where(s => s != string.Empty)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, sometimes you want to put the string back together again after acting on the non-whitespace elements. In such a case it is usually WRONG to treat successive whitespace as a single delimiter.

Comment: I think, @RossPresser, that that is covered by my qualifier "under all but the most obscure scenarios" because even when wanting to recombine the elements I would be hard-pressed to have a case where I care about multiple spaces. I would want a canonical form--one space between each. So I respectfully disagree--it would be "rarely wrong" rather than "usually wrong".

Comment: `CapitalizeEveryWord("This is line one.\n \nThis is line three.")`

Comment: If you truly think that this is obscure, then I guess we'll have to agree to disagree, but if I left this function out of my software I'd lose my job. Users like their content to look the way they want it to look.

Comment: Ah, well, I was a bit too-focused on "space" rather than "whitespace"; thanks for the nudge, @Ross. Though, since my comment just above does use "space" I stand by that as valid :-)... but as you point out it is _not_ as valid for whitespace in general.

Comment: I am wondering why you added `.Where(s => s != string.Empty)` to the Regex. Since you specify `\s+` (any number of spaces) there can be no empty item in between.

Comment: @JackMiller That removes the items generated when leading and/or trailing whitespace is present.

Comment: I find frequently myself dealing with code that cares about the nth string of the split input. Without the 'RemoveEmptyEntries' I would get a space where I was expecting non-space characters.

Comment: I really liked your answer (thanks!), nevertheless @RossPresser 's observation (in the first comment) is quite relevant.

Answer (score 48):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx#Y12) :

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

So just call `myStr.Split();` There's no need to pass in anything because *separator* is a `params` array.

Answer (score 12):

Why dont you use?:

```
string[] ssizes = myStr.Split(' ', '\t');
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that adjacent whitespace will NOT be treated as a single delimiter, even when using `String.Split(null)`. If any of your tokens are separated with multiple spaces or tabs, you'll get empty strings returned in your array.

From the documentation:

> Each element of separator defines a separate delimiter character. If
>   two delimiters are adjacent, or a delimiter is found at the beginning
>   or end of this instance, the corresponding array element contains
>   Empty.

Answer (score 2):

So don't copy and paste! Extract a function to do your splitting and reuse it.

```
public static string[] SplitWhitespace (string input)
{
    char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
    return input.Split(whitespace);
}
```

Code reuse is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> var FirstString = YourString.Split().First();

to split a string and get its first occurrence before the space.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this:

```
var ssizes = myStr.Split(" \t".ToCharArray());
```

It seems there is a method [`String.ToCharArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) in .NET 4.0!

**EDIT:** As VMAtm has pointed out, [the method already existed in .NET 2.0!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This method is in .NET 2.0!!! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it inline?

```
var sizes = subject.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });
```

Otherwise, if you do this exact thing often, you could always create constant or something containing that char array.

As others have noted you can according to the documentation also use `null` or an empty array. When you do that it will use whitespace characters automatically.

```
var sizes = subject.Split(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If repeating the same code is the issue, write an extension method on the String class that encapsulates the splitting logic.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, sorry.

Comment: p. campbell: Yes it does: OP asked for a solution that doesn't require copying the character array everywhere. An obvious solution is to create a function to do the task. This answer points out that such a function could be an extension method. (The answer could be improved, by showing the code to do so...)

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use Below Code.

```
string[] sepratedStrings = s.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just do:

```
string myStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string[] ssizes = myStr.Split(' ');
```

MSDN has more examples and references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx