# How to correctly represent a whitespace character

Tags: c#

I wanted to know how to represent a whitespace character in C#. I found the empty string representation `string.Empty`. Is there anything like that that represents a whitespace character?

I would like to do something like this:

```
test.ToLower().Split(string.Whitespace)
//test.ToLower().Split(Char.Whitespace)
```

Comment: wouldn't it just be a single space? (or the ascii equivilant?)

Comment: Whitespace is a set of characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to specify whitespace in a String.Split operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation)

Comment: a white space character is not just a space, accoording to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9a023cx.aspx `Space, tab, linefeed, carriage-return, formfeed, vertical-tab, and newline characters are called "white-space characters" because they serve the same purpose as the spaces between words and lines on a printed page — they make reading easier`

Comment: `' '` 10 more to go...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*Which* whitespace character? The empty string is pretty unambiguous - it's a sequence of 0 characters. However, `" "`, `"\t"` and `"\n"` are all strings containing a single character which is characterized as whitespace.

If you just mean a space, use a space. If you mean some other whitespace character, there may well be a custom escape sequence for it (e.g. `"\t"` for tab) or you can use a Unicode escape sequence (`"\uxxxx"`). I would discourage you from including non-ASCII characters in your source code, particularly whitespace ones.

EDIT: Now that you've explained what you want to do (which should have been in your question to start with) you'd be better off using [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx) with a regular expression of `\s` which represents whitespace:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s");
string[] bits = regex.Split(text.ToLower());
```

See the [Regex Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z) documentation for more information on other character classes.

Comment: Hi, I am refering to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation. As I had the same problem. I have a csv file where the space was not matching ' ' in the split function. I would like to put string.Whitespace in the function if one exists.

Comment: @Luke101: It would have been useful if you'd said all of this to start with. See my edit - basically you should use regular expressions.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Will clarify posts in the future.

Answer (score 11):

The WhiteSpace CHAR can be referenced using [ASCII Codes here.](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table)
And Character# 32 represents a white space, Therefore:

```
char space = (char)32;
```

For example, you can use this approach to produce desired number of white spaces anywhere you want:

```
int _length = {desired number of white spaces}
string.Empty.PadRight(_length, (char)32));
```

Answer (score 9):

No, there isn't such constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use Unicode character, for me personally this is the most clear solution:

```
var space = "\u0020"
```

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same problem so what I did was create a string with a white space and just index the character.

```
String string = "Hello Morning Good Night";

char empty =  string.charAt(5);
```

Now whenever I need a empty character I will pull it from my reference in memory.

Comment: You may want to check the answer from @david  - `char space = (char)32;`

Answer (score 1):

Which whitespace character?  The most common is the normal space, which is between each word in my sentences.  This is just `" "`.

Comment: I used 'SPACE' instead of "SPACE" to represent space character in c#

Comment: `' '` is a `char`, `" "` is a `string`. In the context of `Split`, the `char` is probably what you want to use. So yeah, you're right

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions, you can represent any whitespace character with the metacharacter "\s"

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic8)