# Difference between IsNullOrEmpty and IsNullOrWhiteSpace in C#

Tags: c#, string, difference, isnullorempty, string-function

What are differences between these commands in C#

```
string text= "  ";
1-string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim())

2-string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
```

Comment: refer to :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx

Comment: "`IsNullOrWhiteSpace` covers `IsNullOrEmpty`" (see TGH answer).

Answer (score 258, accepted):

- [**Source: MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

> `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is a convenience method that is similar to the
>   following code, except that it offers superior performance:
>
> ```
> return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;
> ```
>
> White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard. The
>   `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method interprets any character that returns a
>   value of true when it is passed to the `Char.IsWhiteSpace` method as a
>   white-space character.

Comment: Actually the trimmed string length test will also catch empty strings, so

Answer (score 119):

**Short answer:**

In common use, space `" "`, Tab `"\t"` and newline `"\n"` are the difference:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\t"); //true
string.IsNullOrEmpty("\t"); //false

string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(" "); //true
string.IsNullOrEmpty(" "); //false

string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\n"); //true
string.IsNullOrEmpty("\n"); //false
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4hkpKM

also see this answer about: [whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11019579/1315444%20sdf)

---

**Long answer:**

There are also a few other white space characters, you probably never used before

- Members of the UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator category, which includes the characters `SPACE (U+0020), NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0), OGHAM SPACE MARK (U+1680), EN QUAD (U+2000), EM QUAD (U+2001), EN SPACE (U+2002), EM SPACE (U+2003), THREE-PER-EM SPACE (U+2004), FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (U+2005), SIX-PER-EM SPACE (U+2006), FIGURE SPACE (U+2007), PUNCTUATION SPACE (U+2008), THIN SPACE (U+2009), HAIR SPACE (U+200A), NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F), MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F), and IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE (U+3000)`.
- Members of the UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator category, which consists solely of the `LINE SEPARATOR character (U+2028)`.
- Members of the UnicodeCategory.ParagraphSeparator category, which consists solely of the `PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR character (U+2029)`.
- The characters `CHARACTER TABULATION (U+0009), LINE FEED (U+000A), LINE TABULATION (U+000B), FORM FEED (U+000C), CARRIAGE RETURN (U+000D), and NEXT LINE (U+0085)`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace

Comment: What about `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("")` ?

Comment: @samusarin no difference https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uWpvh

Answer (score 62):

The first method checks if a string is null or a blank string. In your example you can risk a null reference since you are not checking for null before trimming

```
1- string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim())
```

The second method checks if a string is null or an arbitrary number of spaces in the string (including a blank string)

```
2- string .IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
```

The method `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` covers `IsNullOrEmpty`, but it also returns `true` if the string contains only white space characters.

In your concrete example you should use 2) as you run the risk of a null reference exception in approach 1) since you're calling trim on a string that may be null

Comment: with c#6 you can do `string.IsNullOrEmpty(text?.Trim())` safely

Comment: So its always better to use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` than `IsNullOrEmpty` ?

Answer (score 13):

This is **implementation of methods** after decompiling.

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) 
    {
        return (value == null || value.Length == 0); 
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) 
    {
        if (value == null) return true; 

        for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) { 
            if(!Char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i])) return false; 
        }

        return true;
    }
```

So it is obvious that **IsNullOrWhiteSpace** method also checks if value that is being passed contain white spaces.

Whitespaces refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nice, : ) How did you decompile to look at the implementation  ?

Comment: Using decompiler like dotpeek

Answer (score 12):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty(string value)` returns `true` if the string is null or empty. 
For reference an empty string is represented by ""  (two double quote characters)

`String.IsNullOrWhitespace(string value)` returns `true` if the string is null, empty, or contains only whitespace characters such as a space or tab.

To see what characters count as whitespace consult this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If your string (In your case the variable `text`) could be null this would make a big Difference:

1-`string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim())` 
 --> **EXCEPTION** since your calling a mthode of a null object

2-`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)`
 This would work fine since the null issue is beeing checked internally

To provide the same behaviour using the 1st Option you would have to check somehow if its not null first then use the trim() method

```
if ((text != null) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim())) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

***String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)*** should be used in most cases as **it also includes a blank strings with whitespaces but no other text**.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            var str = "";
            
            Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str));              
            
        }
    }
}
```

It returns **True**!

Comment: Your example is not correct since `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will return true for variable `str`.

Comment: @Azimuth I'm not able to understand properly. Can you please create a fiddle on https://rextester.com/ or any other C# online Fiddle Tool that you prefer?

Comment: why should I provide some fiddle? Just replace `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` with `IsNullOrEmpty` in your code and run it. It will return `true`. Thus, your example doesn't show the difference between `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: sure I'll do that. Thanks @Azimuth for explaining.

Comment: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace returns this expression String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0; So, use it in textbox of entry(xamarin) validation handlers

Answer (score 1):

[Performance Test] just in case anyone is wondering, in a stopwatch test comparing

if(nopass.Trim().Length > 0)

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nopass))

---

---

these were the results:

Trim-Length with empty value = 15

Trim-Length with not empty value = 52

---

IsNullOrWhiteSpace with empty value = 11

IsNullOrWhiteSpace with not empty value = 12