# Standard C# variable for whitespace?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any standard C# variable for whitespace?
Something similar to `Environment.NewLine`. I didn't find anything online.
I want to find the index of a whitespace in a given string.

For example

I can do `string.indexOf(" ")`

But I was wondering if there is anything in-built variable in C#.

Comment: Adding more to your question might aid others in helping.  Why do you need something to provide whitespace?  What have you attempted or looked at?

Comment: What all do you consider whitespace? Just space and horizontal tab?

Comment: just space is good for me.

Comment: If you want only space, what you have is fine, or, if you want to use a C# defined value, try the answer provided by Mustafa Çetin below.  As pointed out by itsme86 "white space" can mean more than a single space.  This is also covered by Jon Skeet in an answer to a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019561/how-to-correctly-represent-a-whitespace-character

Comment: The only reason Newline exists is because it is actually variable, operating systems do no agree about what a line-ending should look like.  Nobody disagrees about an ascii space.  Or the many Unicode spaces.  I probably should not mention the [Space() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.space(v=vs.110).aspx) in everybody's favorite utility namespace, that would be gauche.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there in-built variable or function but maybe this can help you

```
int indexOfWhiteSpace(string input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: OP should note that this is more than just a space - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But he already want more than just a space so what is problem. I didt understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be

```
text.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Count();
```

Although just seen that you said it's only space you are after so I think your original code is fine. I guess you could do:

```
test.IndexOf(' ');
```

Which would keep it to a single character (but probably make little difference other than ensure you didn't accidentally type two spaces!)