# C# - Split string by any number of tabs and spaces

Tags: c#, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to specify whitespace in a String.Split operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation)

I am trying to read in the hosts file that contains:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
ect...
```

So as I read it in line by line I need to grab the IP and the host name but how would I grab them if they are formated by any number of tabs or spaces or both.

```
127.0.0.1<tab><space>localhost
127.0.0.1<space>localhost
127.0.0.1<space><space><space><space>localhost
```

Comment: Just read the entire line until a return character.  Once you have entire line break it up into two strings one which contains 
`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[whitespace]........alpha characters`

Comment: I think people jumped the gun in marking this as a duplicate. The linked question isn't quite the same as this question, and the accepted answer there doesn't do the right thing

Answer (score 37):

```
var components = host.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: can we use above somehow to include whitespaces and other character like a , ?

Comment: @Muds Sure. Explicitly specify the desired separators in the first argument.

Comment: thanks for replying, i did try to do but it isnt accepting it as correct format

Comment: @Muds What did you try, and what error did you get?

Comment: host.Split('a','b',(char)null);

Comment: @Muds The first argument is an array, so you'll need to do something like this: `host.Split(new [] {'a', 'b'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. Or you can just do this if you don' care about removing empty components: `host.Split('a', 'b')` - which works because this overload uses `params`.

Comment: branko, i intended to split on a, b and any white space, hence was  willing to pass a null, removing empty entries wont serve the purpose

Comment: @Muds And as I said: _"Explicitly specify the desired separators in the first argument."_. I don't think you can combine non-space and space separators like you attempted - you'll have to explicitly list the whitespaces (and non-whitespaces) you are interested in (the full list of whitespaces is here: [Char.IsWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace)), or implement your own method that makes use of `Char.IsWhiteSpace`.

Comment: split(null) of split(char[0]) works hence i was just wondering if we could just cast null to char and use it but doesnt seem to be right option as for now