# C#: Split returns empty string

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to split a string like

```
0 2 5 6 8 13
```

by using

```
string[] exampleStringArray = exampleString.Split(null)
```

However, I don't end up getting the strings

```
0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 13
```

in my array but there is one **empty** string at the index 0. How do I prevent this from happening?

And no, I cannot have a string array at the very beginning with these numbers.

**Edit**: This question is 10 months old but I revisited it and don't understand why it was marked as a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954216/) question. My problem was an empty string at the beginning of an array, their problem was about splitting a string with multiple whitespaces between the needed values.

Comment: Passing null is not sensible, you have to specify the character(s) you want to split on.  So probably `' '`.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought so too but for some reason it works in removing a single whitespace which is not at the start or end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`SplitStringOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) flag with an overload such as:

<s>" 0 2 5 6 8 13".Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)</s>

Seems `null` [*is* a valid option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

> If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard; they return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

But in order to use with the `RemoveEmptyEntries` flag you need to explicitly cast the type to `char[]` or `string[]` in order to resolve the method overload.

```
" 0 2 5 6 8 13".Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about the overload.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you split on NULL?

you have to split with Space ' '

here is working example:  http://rextester.com/CXCB9931

Good luck.

Comment: According to the documentation of String.Split null is a valid option and splits by all whitespaces.