# How can I use Empty literal on Split('')

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I need to read a string with non-space separated values (0-9).
Why can't I use Empty literal in *String.Split* method?

```
// Reading Grid's row and col size
gridInputValues = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
gridRow = int.Parse(gridInputValues[0]);
gridCol = int.Parse(gridInputValues[1]);
gridMatrix2D = new int[gridRow, gridCol];
// Reading Grid's row * col matrix values
for( int r = 0; r < gridRow; r++ ) 
{
    //string[] inputVal = Console.ReadLine().Split('');
    //string[] inputVal = Console.ReadLine().Split(string.Empty));
    string inputVal = Console.ReadLine();
    for( int c = 0; c < gridCol; c++ ) 
    {
        //gridMatrix2D[r, c] = int.Parse(inputVal[c]);
        gridMatrix2D[r, c] = int.Parse(inputVal[c].ToString());
    }
```

Why not,

```
string[] inputVal = Console.ReadLine().Split('');
```

or

```
string[] inputVal = Console.ReadLine().Split(string.Empty));
```

works?

Alternatively,
Is using *string.ToString* good practice in such case?

or

Will the *string.ToString* method on each iteration increase the running time?

#### EDIT 1:

Input:

```
 "12345" // type is string
```

Expected Output:

```
 "1","2","3","4","5" // type is string[]
```

Comment: Because Empty != whitespace.

Comment: What should such a split return? Where SHOULD it split if you don´t provide a delimier? On every character? On every second? Furthermore: What is your inout-string that you read?

Comment: What does splitting a string by empty string mean? Isn't that equal to calling `string.ToCharArray()` or just enumerating the string?

Comment: You can access a char in a string already like if the string was a `char[]`: `char c = inputVal[c]`. No need to create an array.

Comment: If I use character Array, I need to call ToString() each time before parsing it to interger. I think it'll increase my running time? Isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to specify whitespace in a String.Split operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation)

Comment: Please update the question with example input and expected output of the `Split('')`

Comment: Actually, my code works fine. I want to know if it's a good practice to split?
and why not empty string literal works.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use chars:

```
int[] intArray = inputVal.Select(ch => ch-'0').ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your alternate solution. :)

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
Console.ReadLine().ToArray()
```

You don´t seem to need split the string, you just want the individual characters.

or [String.ToCharArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) as @Tim Schmelter correctly pointed out.

Comment: If I use it, I still need to use <i> string.ToString </i> method at parsing, which may increase the running time.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV dont worry ToString will not affect performance that much. It wont be the bottleneck part of your code. Even for million ToString calls should not affect that much

Comment: @Akhgary Thank you for your info on my performance doubt. :) Any idea about Why empty literal is not allowed in split method?

Comment: @NaveenKumarV in fact the split method will search inside string and will perform split if it find any matches inside string. The search method should access the elements of string like `"example"[i]`. So It access the elements of string just like arrays. The problem is you cant get empty string or empty char for any given `i`. empty string is non existence and you cant get a non existing thing.

Comment: Also this can be the reason why empty char is not allowed. `''`. Because it does not exist. If you assume it exist then it will be all over your string. Consider `"Hello"[1]`. It should give you character `'e'` or `''`? Thats the problem. I hope you understand what i mean @NaveenKumarV

Comment: @Akhgary :). Yeah. This seems reasonable. Anyway thanks for your effort to make me understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try this

```
string[] inputVal = Console.ReadLine().Split(null);
```

or

```
string[] inputVal = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: It's for white Space. But I want each character in a string. For example, "12345" should be splitted as "1","2","3","4","5".