# using the string.split function but getting an unexpected result

Tags: c#, string

So i am attempting to make a calculator and I am unsure of how to take the equation and split it up into operators and operands. I have chosen to do this by using the string.split function to turn it into an array of numbers and operators to which i can then compare and output the result. However I want to throw and error if the user enters " + 100" as it will expect a operand first. This is my code to check the above condition

```
String equation = txt_equation.Text;
String[] equationArray= new String [30];
equationArray = equation.Split(' ');

if (equationArray[0] == "+" || equationArray[0] == "-" || equationArray[0] == "/" || equationArray[0] == "*")
{
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The equation entered is incorrect");
}
else
{...}
```

The problem is when I enter *"100 + 100"* it does get split up as:

> equationArray[0] = "100"
>   equationArray[1] = "+"
>   equationArray[2] = "100"

but if I enter *" + 100"* the result is:

> equationArray[0] = ""
>   equationArray[1] = "+"
>   equationArray[2] = "100"

*Side note users enter in the numbers / operands with buttons numbers are entered into the equation as "n" operands as " operator " allowing the spaces to break it up*

Comment: _String.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)_ The " + 100" contains an initial space that produces an empty element in the destination array. By the way, you don't need to initialize the destination array

Comment: That worked thanks :)

Comment: More info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation?rq=1 (look at the second best answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is a space before `+`, so it will split there with an empty string on one side and `+` on the other.

You might find the [option to remove empty entries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) useful - this would also result in collapsing multiple spaces between tokens.

> `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to **omit empty array elements from the array returned**; or `StringSplitOptions.None` to include empty array elements in the array returned.

```
equation.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also assume "`1  +  2`" is legal, i.e. in general whitespace of any length is only of relevance for splitting tokens ?  Therefore you need to use an overload of `Split` that takes a `StringSplitOptions` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx and specify `RemoveEmptyEntries`

Answer (score -1):

if you wanted the application to check if it is a *legit whole number*, you could just add `equationArray[0] == null || equationArray[0] == "" || equationArray[0] == " "` to your if statement.