# Split a string based on white space in C#

Tags: c#, string, list, split

I have a string "dexter is  good    annd        bad".

I want create a list by splitting this string based on the space.

I have achieved this using following code

```
string ss = "dexter is  good    annd        bad";
    var s = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss) && ss!= "null"? ss.Split(' ').ToList(): new List<string>();
```

The problem is this list also contains spaces, I don't need spaces or empty string to be in my list.

Comment: This is duplicate question, and offered answers are not optimal. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` method:

```
var s = ss.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Regex.Split Method from System.Text.RegularExpressions:

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(ss, @"\s+");
```