# Get as string a part of an line from a text

Tags: c#, regex, readline

I have some lines of a file and i have to get from it as a string just the firsts characters.
The text is:

```
...
(spaces) UWORD (spaces) /* data */

(spaces) UBYTE (spaces) /* data */
....
```

I have to get "UWORD" and "UBYTE" and more of that from all lines without any spaces or /*data */

```
while ((line = Readed.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("data") )
    {
             // DO WHAT? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a concrete example with few lines to read and an example of what you expect to get from those lines

Comment: `string word = line.Trim().Split(null).First();`

Comment: @bommelding sounds good but what is the `null` good for ?

Comment: The null is shorthand for all whitespace and maybe some control chars

Comment: Could you provide an example (several lines of a file), please?

Comment: @bommelding nice trick. Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6111355/5174469) thanx mate :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) overload with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. It will:

> Splits a string into substrings based on the strings in an array.

in this case split the string by spaces. Now you need to take just the first element:

```
string input = @"   UWORD     /* data */ ";
string value = input.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
```

EDIT: this looks like you are scanning code and retrieve datatype names. In this case you might have not only spaces but also tabs. If this is the case just include also tabs into the string array that holds the delimiters:

```
string value = input.Split(new string[] {" ", "\t"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
```

Apparently it is also possible to catch [all whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6111355/5174469). Here is the trick to do that:

```
string value = input.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The last code did the job with the whitespaces characters. The second works too.

Comment: @LunculescuBogdan glad to hear. I though you might encounter also some tabs in there

Comment: if you flag my answer for deletion. Just speak to me with a reasonable argument. I will ask to unaccept my answer and delete it myself.