# How can i ignore empty space when doing a split in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#

I have a string as follows,

```
  var str = '  test'
```

when i call the expression

```
 str.split(' ')  I end up with 2 items in an array.
```

How can i split it and end up with only test, ie something that has a non-empty space in c# ?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the space, or get a list of all of the words, and then remove all empty members?

Comment: I am trying to remove the white spaces and get a count of the words

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify how "a lambda expression?" is related to the body of the post. Additionally showing your research on what `Split` (upper case, not some strange `split` shown in the post) function do would be nice.

Comment: The problem description isn't really clear to me.  (1) This isn't C# code.  (2) When I correct the syntax to *be* C# code, I don't end up with 2 items in the array but 3.  (3) What is "a non-empty space"?  (4) How is a lambda expression involved at all?  Overall, can you update this to a [mcve] and indicate specifically what result you observe when debugging vs. what result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but this still solves the problem:

```
List<string> strings = str.Split(' ').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
int stringCount = strings.Count();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `StringSplitOptions` overload:

```
var str = "  test    words cat  dog   ";
String[] words = str.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int wordCount = words.Length;
foreach(String word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
Console.WriteLine("Count: " + wordCount);
```

Comment: He left a comment that clarifies that he's also trying to get a count of the words, but yeah, this is close enough.

Comment: @JoshHeaps Added in a count of words.

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.Trim().Split(' ')` this will strip away leading and trailing whitespace. If you're trying to turn `"   a string with words   "` into `["a", "string", "with", "words"]` this will achieve that.

You'll still have to account for extra spaces between the words though

Edit: this is a much better answer (essentiall use Regex or `str.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410393/5278363

Comment: How would those extra spaces be accounted for?

Comment: @JoshHeaps you mean extra spaces in the middle? that's why your solution is better, but I do still think Trim() is relevant

Comment: Trim() removes whitespace, and `Split()` will remove the character passed

Comment: @JoshHeaps yes that's correct, but if there are multiple spaces in between words, he'll have extra elements in the array: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HirF4r