# VB.Net Read Text from file and put the in the TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I got the data from a text file as follows:

> KILL
>       MAD
>     JOG
>    JUG

From the above data I want to put the text "Kill" in Textbox 1, the text "MAD" in textbox 2, the text "JOG" in the textbox 3, and "JUG" in the textbox 4
The following screenshot

[Click Here](http://prntscr.com/5686j7)

So, anyone can help me ?

Comment: _"and continuous"_ ask one question in each question. By modifying your questions you make all answers that were correct at the time they were posted now incorect. Also, if you have multiple lines how do you want to show them in a single pair of textboxes? You should consider to use a different control like `DataGridView`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string at all whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562981/splitting-a-string-at-all-whitespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
Dim bothTokens As String() = text.Split() ' uses white-space characters as delimiter
textboxt1.Text = bothTokens(0) ' or bothTokens.First()
textboxt2.Text = bothTokens(1) ' or bothTokens.Last()
```

This splits by all [white-space characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx(v=vs.110).aspx)(also by new-line or tab), if you only want to split by space use `text.Split(" "c)` instead of `Split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim s As String = "KILL09 fre0912"
Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {" "c})
textBox1.Text = parts(0)
textBox2.Text = parts(0)
```